# How to get positions of rotated coordinate before rotation?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, rotation

I am trying to rotate an image and the rotated image has some holes or missing pixels. In order to get the color that should fill the missing pixel, I need to get the position of where the missing pixel would be in the not-rotated image.

To calculate the pixel coordinate after rotation I do this

```
double rotationAsRadiant = Math.toRadians( 360 - rotationInDegrees );
double cos = Math.cos( rotationAsRadiant );
double sin = Math.sin( rotationAsRadiant );
int xAfterRotation = (int)( x * cos + y * sin );
int yAfterRotation = (int)( -x * sin + y * cos );
```

How can I get the x and y used in calculating xAfterRotation and yAfterRotation?

Comment: `x` and `y` are the inputs to this formula - I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for. Are you interested in inverting the function? You could also just rotate by a negative angle.

Comment: Just one guess: are you doing this formula in two nested loops for `x` and `y`? This might well be the root cause of your problem, and if my guess is correct, I can suggest a solution using a different approach.

Comment: Yes, I want to invert the function. Without knowing the x and y inputs, how can I get the x and y inputs from the xAfterRotation and yAfterRotation variables?

Comment: Can't you just replace `360 - rotationInDegrees` with `rotationInDegrees`? That will undo the rotation. Not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I am rotating the image by looping trough all pixels using a nested for loop for x and y yes.

Comment: So you're looping through the x and y coordinates of the original (unrotated) image? Try doing it the other way. Loop through the x and y coordinates of the rotated image (adding additional margins where necessary). Rotate these back to the image's x and y coordinates, and discard cases where x and/or y lie outside the image's boundary.

Comment: @r3mainer I'll try that idea, thanks! But won't I need the same formula I am struggling to get now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the formula like in:

```
double rotationAsRadiant = Math.toRadians( rotationInDegrees );
double cos = Math.cos( rotationAsRadiant );
double sin = Math.sin( rotationAsRadiant );
for (int xAfter = 0; xAfter < width; xAfter++) {
    for (int yAfter = 0; yAfter < height; yAfter++) {
        int xBefore = (int)( xAfter * cos + yAfter * sin );
        int yBefore = (int)( -xAfter * sin + yAfter * cos );
        // paint pixel xAfter/yAfter using original from xBefore/yBefore
        ...
    }
}
```

This way, you will surely fill all pixels of the resulting image, with the original pixel closest to the exact position. There will be no holes.

Your original approach was driven by the question "Where does a given source pixel go in the destination image?". There's no guarantee that the results will cover all pixels (you've seen holes).

My approach goes along the question "For a given destination pixel, where do I find its source?".